# ng-Grid allow the selection to show when a row is selected that is using a rowTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

Is there a way to allow the selection to show when a row is selected that is using a rowTemplate?

I tried setting the `.ngRow.selected` background-color as `!important` but it don't seem to work. Is there another way?

Comment: Do you have a plunker that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Jip here is a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/c5QEyIhQZDNsJ7NR2fm4?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perhaps not the prettiest way, but you need to bring the selected class into your rowTemplate.

```js
ng-class="{ selected: row.selected, green: row.getProperty(\'age\') < 30}"
```

And then update your CSS:

```css
.ngRow .selected{ 
  background-color:blue!important;
}
```

Here's a demonstration plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wyjO3F5xEDtN9tmDGSpU?p=preview